# 'select all' and 'remove all' with chosen.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

For the select menu plugin [chosen.js](http://github.com/harvesthq/chosen), is there an established way to add 'select all items in list' or 'remove all items in list' feature to a multiple select input? In the main branch or perhaps in one of the forks? Or has someone done this before has some tips?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It should be pretty straight forward, just do it the "normal" way first:

```
$('.my-select-all').click(function(){
    $('#my_select option').prop('selected', true); // Selects all options
});
```

Then trigger the `liszt:updated` event to update the chosen widget, so the whole thing would look something like this:

---

**Update**: For those who don't [scroll down and check the other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18376240/398242), the event is called `chosen:updated` as of a version released in August 2013. Consult the [documentation](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) if in doubt.

---

```
<select multiple>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<button class="select">Select all</button>
<button class="deselect">Deselect all</button>
```

```
$('select').chosen();
$('.select').click(function(){
    $('option').prop('selected', true);
    $('select').trigger('liszt:updated');
});
$('.deselect').click(function(){
    $('option').prop('selected', false);
    $('select').trigger('liszt:updated');
});​
```

Working demo (js code is at the bottom): http://jsfiddle.net/C7LnL/1/

Tighter version: http://jsfiddle.net/C7LnL/2/

Even tighter version: http://jsfiddle.net/C7LnL/3/

Comment: well done @wesley - i figured it would be something along those lines. a great help!

Comment: `trigger('liszt:updated')` is the key, even if you stop using chosen the code will still work.

Comment: when desselecting all select items i had a problem with updating the div display items , i solve it wit this : `$('div#mySelect_chzn ul.chzn-choices li.search-choice').remove();`

Comment: Don't forget about e.preventDefault(); otherwise you will get effect of "flashing select and deselect"

Comment: The event name is not 'liszt:updated' anymore, see Jack's answer bellow.

Comment: instead of $('select').trigger('liszt:updated'); $('select').trigger('chosen:updated'); worked for me.

Answer (score 15):

Try this code it will work 100%

```
// Deselect All
$('#my_select_box option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
$('#my_select_box').trigger('chosen:updated');

// Select All
$('#my_select_box option').prop('selected', true);  
$('#my_select_box').trigger('chosen:updated');
```

Comment: I had to use ( ).prop('selected', false) for the deselect all function.

Answer (score 8):

I missed the similar feature. This adds the two links All and None (texts customizable through options uncheck_all_text and select_all_text) on the top of the popup list. You may need to edit this if you use grouping.

```
$("select").on("chosen:showing_dropdown", function(evnt, params) {
    var chosen = params.chosen,
        $dropdown = $(chosen.dropdown),
        $field = $(chosen.form_field);
    if( !chosen.__customButtonsInitilized ) {
        chosen.__customButtonsInitilized = true;
        var contained = function( el ) {
            var container = document.createElement("div");
            container.appendChild(el);
            return container;
        }
        var width = $dropdown.width();
        var opts = chosen.options || {},
            showBtnsTresshold = opts.disable_select_all_none_buttons_tresshold || 0;
            optionsCount = $field.children().length,
            selectAllText = opts.select_all_text || 'All',
            selectNoneText = opts.uncheck_all_text || 'None';
        if( chosen.is_multiple && optionsCount >= showBtnsTresshold ) {
            var selectAllEl = document.createElement("a"),
                selectAllElContainer = contained(selectAllEl),
                selectNoneEl = document.createElement("a"),
                selectNoneElContainer = contained(selectNoneEl);
            selectAllEl.appendChild( document.createTextNode( selectAllText ) );
            selectNoneEl.appendChild( document.createTextNode( selectNoneText ) );
            $dropdown.prepend("<div class='ui-chosen-spcialbuttons-foot' style='clear:both;border-bottom: 1px solid black;'></div>");
            $dropdown.prepend(selectNoneElContainer);
            $dropdown.prepend(selectAllElContainer);
            var $selectAllEl = $(selectAllEl),
                $selectAllElContainer = $(selectAllElContainer),
                $selectNoneEl = $(selectNoneEl),
                $selectNoneElContainer = $(selectNoneElContainer);
            var reservedSpacePerComp = (width - 25) / 2;
            $selectNoneElContainer.addClass("ui-chosen-selectNoneBtnContainer")
                .css("float", "right").css("padding", "5px 8px 5px 0px")
                .css("max-width", reservedSpacePerComp+"px")
                .css("max-height", "15px").css("overflow", "hidden");
            $selectAllElContainer.addClass("ui-chosen-selectAllBtnContainer")
                .css("float", "left").css("padding", "5px 5px 5px 7px")
                .css("max-width", reservedSpacePerComp+"px")
                .css("max-height", "15px").css("overflow", "hidden");
            $selectAllEl.on("click", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $field.children().prop('selected', true);
                $field.trigger('chosen:updated');
                return false;
            });
            $selectNoneEl.on("click", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $field.children().prop('selected', false);
                $field.trigger('chosen:updated');
                return false;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I am also using a CSS to limit the height of the selected choises in case there are say tens of them:

```
    .chosen-choices {
        max-height: 150px;
    }
```

Comment: This seems the best option because it adapts to select. I really liked the result.

Answer (score 5):

Just straight forward way of clearing selection:

```
$('select').val('');
$('select').val('').trigger("chosen:updated");
```

Comment: Close but you need to update the control. $('select').val('').trigger("chosen:updated");

Answer (score 2):

I realize this question is quite old, but I came upon a similar issue and wanted to share my result, as I like it's simplicity:

I created two buttons (all and none) and floated them left and right inside the div containing my select dropdown. The buttons look something like this:

```
<button style="float:left;" class="btn" id="iAll">All</button>
<button style="float:right;" class="btn" id="iNone">None</button>
```

Then I added some Jquery to handle the button actions:

```
$('#iAll').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#iSelect option').prop('selected', true).trigger('chosen:updated');
});

$('#iNone').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#iSelect option:selected").removeAttr("selected").trigger('chosen:updated');
});
```

Will probably need some cleaning up with regards to layout, but it's quite functional as is and I thought I'd share.

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#ctrlName option:selected").removeAttr("selected").trigger('liszt:updated');
```

clear all

```
$("#ctrlName option").attr("selected","selected").trigger('liszt:updated');
```

select all

Answer (score -3):

You should try this:

```
$('#drpdwn').empty();
$('#drpdwn').trigger('chosen:updated');
```

Comment: This removes all elements from the dropdown and prevents any from being selected later.