# Select all in jquery chosen plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery-chosen

I am trying to select all using the chosen plugin but I have failed in all my attempts. I am using the following code. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I implemented this using: ['select all' and 'remove all' with chosen.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172269/select-all-and-remove-all-with-chosen-js)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/jpg" href="hanken_logo.jpg">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="chosen/chosen.min.css?v=<?php echo time(); ?>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css?v=<?php echo time(); ?>">
    <title>Data Portal</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="Header">
    <p class="Message">Data</p>>
  </div>
    <div class="container_data">
        Select Variables
        <select multiple data-placeholder="Select..." class="chosen-select">
          <option hidden selected value=""></option>
          <option value="1">Firm Size</option>
          <option value="2">Firm Age</option>
          <option value="3">Market-to-Book</option>
          <option value="4">Return on Assets</option>
          <option value="5">Return on Equity</option>
        </select>
        <button class="select">Select all</button>
        <button class="deselect">Deselect all</button>
          <script src="jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
          <script src="chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
          $('select').chosen();
            $('.select').click(function(){
              $('option').prop('selected', true);
              $('select').trigger('liszt:updated');
            });
            $('.deselect').click(function(){
              $('option').prop('selected', false);
              $('select').trigger('liszt:updated');
            });​
          </script>
      </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `$('select').trigger('liszt:updated');` to `$('select').trigger('chosen:updated');`